# How to modify my flask application once i put it on to the linux server?

Tags: linux, flask, deployment, server

Original question:
I just deployed my first Flask application on an Ubuntu server from Linod. However, the website works as I expected but now I am wondering how to make changes on my application.

(updated)
I apologize for my past question being too vague. Now I firgued out I can do " remote development" by using the Pycharm IDE (profassional version)

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Git is such an amazing system, that it is always worth learning. If you start using it, you will regret not learning to sooner.

Once your Git system is set up, it can indeed be as simple as just running

```
$ sudo git pull
```

on your server to get the newest code changes, but that depends on your application, it's dependencies and the overall setup of your server.

There is a myriad of material on the internet to help you dive into this topic. I would recommend you take a day to explore and find out about topics like *version control*, *Git*, *continuous deployment* etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!